# excel formula localization

Tags: excel, vba, localization, locale

I developed a macro heavy excel file with multiple country tabs that are intended to be updated by people in different countries.

I am having a trouble with a user that updated the file with the excel with Russian locale settings. Somehow formulas in the tab(where she did changes) were translated into Russian (SUM -> СУММ) and when another colleague with the German locale settings opened the file, only these formulas were not translated back to German(the file was pretty much broken). The German user could still see the Russian formuals. The other English formulas were properly translated to German.

I am looking for a way to:

1. Either stick to English locale in the file on all systems;
2. or to make sure that formula translation is done properly.

I will appreciate any hint.
Thanks!

Comment: Did something similar back when it was excel macro language, first thing macro did on starting was to ascertain locale settings and set variables accordingly.

Comment: Sounds like a big to me. When opened in German locale, do the Russian formula still work? And can you reproduce the issue in a macro free Workbook?

Comment: Only a minor possibility: did you check auto-correct options, as `SUM` might be included?

Comment: @T.M. checked auto-correct but it seems to be fine. Thank you for the idea though!

Comment: @chrisneilsen no, Russian formulas are shown in the German version but give name errors. I am going to client location to their excel settings in oder to reproduce it. I could not really neither reproduce it or find a solution so far.

Comment: @SolarMike interesting! thanks for the idea! i will check it out